# i need to find the first negative number in each column of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector, match

Hello i need to find the position of first negative number for each row vector in a matrix

i've tried with match and apply but it ony shows the first

```
z<-matrix(c(-3,2,-1,3,2,-2,3,-4,-1),ncol=3)
k<-z<0
h<-apply(k,1,function(x) match(TRUE,k))
```

i want it to show [1,3,2]
but it shows only the first match of the entire matrix [1,1,1]

Answer (score 3):

We can use `max.col` with `ties.method = "first"` to get first negative number

```
max.col(z < 0, ties.method = "first")
#[1] 1 3 1
```

With `apply` you could do

```
apply(z < 0, 1, which.max)
```

---

Both these approaches require at-least one negative number in the row or else it will return the first index. To avoid that we can check with `rowSums` whether there is at-least one negative number in the row and then use `max.col`. Rows with no negative value would get 0 then.

```
(rowSums(z < 0) > 0) * max.col(z < 0, ties.method = "first")
```

Comment: thank you i used the second one, i know there must be a negative so checking is not required

Answer (score 2):

Alternative modifying OP attempt,

```
apply(z<0, 1, function(x) which(x)[1])
# [1] 1 3 1
```

Has the benefit of when there is no negative in a row, returns NA, not 1.
For example,

```
z2 <- structure(c(-3, 2, -1, 3, 2, -2, 3, 0, -1), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
apply(z2<0, 1, function(x) which(x)[1])
[1]  1 NA  1
```

**Edit**

Bit faster is to use the match function:

```
apply(z<0, 1, function(x) match(TRUE, x))
# [1] 1 3 1
```